# pass value and control from javascript to servlets

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp file with google map, place autocomplete and few buttons. The submit Button click calls a method in Javascript which inturn passes the jsp page 'input' data to callServlet() method as 'params'. I want to call a servlet page MyServlet and pass the params to it. However my callServlet() executes perfectly but doesn't pass on the control/params to  MyServlet.
Also How to read params in MyServlet?

Please help me solve it.

**JS code:**

```
function callServlet(params) {

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "./mapServlet";

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    console.log(url);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            console.log("Its perfect");
        } else {
            alert(xmlhttp.status);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);

    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", params.length); // POST request MUST have a Content-Length header (as per HTTP/1.1)       

// params is of json format with key value pairs
        xmlhttp.send(params);     

    }
```

**Servlet code:** (Made no changes to this page. Its a simple servlet template)

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException { ...    }

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.print("aaas");
    processRequest(request, response);
}

@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

**web.xml**

```
  <servlet>
         <servlet-name>mapServlet</servlet-name>
         <servlet-class>MyServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>mapServlet</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/mapServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a specific reason you're not using jQuery for that?

Basically, xmlhttp.send(params) expects to receive key=value string, not a Json. If you intend to use bare XMLHttpRequest, you'll need to create this string on your own.

Also, this mapping: `var url = "./mapServlet"`; may be wrong, as usually you serve code from root, and your JS files are served from resource directory such as /js. Using `var url = "/mapServlet" would be better.

Finally, after you reach your servlet, you can read your parameters using `request.getParameter("parameter_name")`

To call your server using jQuery start with using jQuery.post() method:

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

```
$.post( "./mapServlet", params)
  .done(function( data ) {
     console.log("Got ", data);
  });
```

Comment: I'm not aware of jQuery solution. can you post it. Besides the url is correct. and i'll try this solution without json as parameter

Comment: hey the jquery prints the  JSP pg  on console after going through MyServlet but doesn't load the jsp page on browser.

Comment: Why would it? You need to replace console.log with actual code for that.